# How can I CSV export a PrimeNG lazy loaded table in Angular 12

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-table

I've tried disabling [lazy] on the table, reloading all the data, and then calling table.exportCSV() but I still only get the currently displayed list of records (none from the other pages).

I think disabling [lazy] might trigger an async process because if I call my code a second time it works - all data exported into CSV.

Is there an event I need to watch for after disabling [lazy] on the table?